# ¿ Cómo hacer para codificar un programa en java para insertar unos datos en la clasificación relativa a esos datos y poder modificarla en mysql?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statements

yo necesitaba saber como hacer eso; con una estructura similar a la de este código:

```
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Class.java to edit this template
 */
package Controlador;

import Modelo.Conexion;
import Modelo.Exportacion;
import Modelo.Metodos;
import Modelo.usuario;
import Vistas.ExportacionVista;
import Vistas.Login;
import Vistas.Registro;
import funciones.Validacion;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/* loaded from: controlador.class */
public class controlador implements ActionListener {
    Metodos met;
    usuario x;
    Exportacion ex;
    Login log;
    Registro reg;
    ExportacionVista exv;
    DefaultTableModel modelo;
    Validacion validacion = new Validacion();

    public controlador(Login log, Registro reg, usuario user, ExportacionVista exv, Exportacion ex, DefaultTableModel modelo, Metodos met) {
        this.met = new Metodos();
        this.x = new usuario();
        this.ex = new Exportacion();
        this.log = new Login();
        this.reg = new Registro();
        this.exv = new ExportacionVista();
        this.modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
        this.log = log;
        this.reg = reg;
        this.x = user;
        this.ex = ex;
        this.exv = exv;
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.met = met;
        this.reg.BtnRegistrar.addActionListener(this);
        this.reg.BtnMenu.addActionListener(this);
        this.reg.BtnSalir.addActionListener(this);
        this.reg.BtnLimpiar.addActionListener(this);
        this.log.btnIngresar.addActionListener(this);
        this.log.BtnRegistro.addActionListener(this);
        this.log.BtnSalir.addActionListener(this);
        this.exv.BtnGuardar.addActionListener(this);
        this.exv.Btnsalir.addActionListener(this);
        this.exv.BtnListar.addActionListener(this);
        this.exv.BtnEditar.addActionListener(this);
        this.exv.BtnActualizar.addActionListener(this);
        this.exv.BtnEiminar.addActionListener(this);
        this.exv.BtnLimpiarF.addActionListener(this);
        this.exv.btnBuscar.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == this.exv.BtnGuardar) {
            try {
                agregar();
                limpiarTabla();
                Listar(this.exv.tabla);
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this.exv, "no se pudo crear Expotación");
            }
        }
        if (e.getSource() == this.exv.Btnsalir) {
            this.log.setVisible(true);
            this.exv.setVisible(false);
        }
        if (e.getSource() == this.exv.BtnListar) {
            Listar(this.exv.tabla);
            limpiarTabla();
            Listar(this.exv.tabla);
        }
        if (e.getSource() == this.exv.BtnEditar) {
            mostrarExportacionParaEditar();
        }
        if (e.getSource() == this.exv.BtnActualizar) {
            actualizarExportacion();
            limpiarFormulario();
            limpiarTabla();
            Listar(this.exv.tabla);
        }
        if (e.getSource() == this.exv.BtnEiminar) {
            delete();
            limpiarFormulario();
            limpiarTabla();
            Listar(this.exv.tabla);
        }
        if (e.getSource() == this.exv.BtnLimpiarF) {
            limpiarFormulario();
            limpiarTabla();
            Listar(this.exv.tabla);
        }
        if (e.getSource() == this.exv.btnBuscar) {
            buscarDatos();
        }
        if (e.getSource() == this.reg.BtnRegistrar) {
            Registrar();
        }
        if (e.getSource() == this.reg.BtnSalir) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if (e.getSource() == this.reg.BtnMenu) {
            this.log.setVisible(true);
            this.reg.setVisible(false);
        }
        if (e.getSource() == this.reg.BtnLimpiar) {
            limpiarFormulario();
        }
        if (e.getSource() == this.log.btnIngresar) {
            Ingreso();
            limpiarFormulario();
        }
        if (e.getSource() == this.log.BtnRegistro) {
            this.reg.setVisible(true);
            this.log.setVisible(false);
        }
        if (e.getSource() == this.log.BtnSalir) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public void iniciar() {
        this.log.setTitle("iniciar sesión ");
        this.log.pack();
        this.log.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
        this.log.setLocationRelativeTo((Component) null);
        this.log.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void Listar(JTable tabla) {
        this.modelo = tabla.getModel();
        List<Exportacion> lista = this.met.Listar();
        Object[] object = new Object[11];
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            object[0] = Integer.valueOf(lista.get(i).getId());
            object[1] = lista.get(i).getNombrePro();
            object[2] = lista.get(i).getPresentacionPro();
            object[3] = lista.get(i).getCantidadPro();
            object[4] = lista.get(i).getTipoEnvio();
            object[5] = lista.get(i).getPaisDestino();
            object[6] = lista.get(i).getCiudadOrigen();
            object[7] = lista.get(i).getCiudadDestino();
            object[8] = lista.get(i).getMonedaPago();
            object[9] = lista.get(i).getNombreEmpleado();
            object[10] = lista.get(i).getNombreFuncionario();
            this.modelo.addRow(object);
        }
        this.exv.tabla.setModel(this.modelo);
    }

    public void agregar() {
        String NombrePro = this.exv.TxtNombreP.getText();
        String PresentacionPro = this.exv.TxtPresentacionProducto.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String CantidadPro = this.exv.TxtCantidad.getText();
        String TipoEnvio = this.exv.TxtEnvio.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String PaisDestino = this.exv.TxtPaises.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String CiudadOrigen = this.exv.TxtCuidadOrigen.getText();
        String CiudadDestino = this.exv.TxtCiudadDestino.getText();
        String MonedaPago = this.exv.TxtMonedaPago.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String NombreEmpleado = this.exv.TxtNombreEmp.getText();
        String NombreFuncionario = this.exv.TxtNombreFunci.getText();
        if (NombrePro.trim().isEmpty() || PresentacionPro.trim().isEmpty() || CantidadPro.trim().isEmpty() || TipoEnvio.trim().isEmpty() || PaisDestino.trim().isEmpty() || CiudadOrigen.trim().isEmpty() || CiudadDestino.trim().isEmpty() || MonedaPago.trim().isEmpty() || NombreEmpleado.trim().isEmpty() || NombreFuncionario.trim().isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) null, "Debe completar todos los datos");
            return;
        }
        try {
            Double.parseDouble(CantidadPro);
            this.ex.setNombrePro(NombrePro);
            this.ex.setPresentacionPro(PresentacionPro);
            this.ex.setCantidadPro(CantidadPro);
            this.ex.setTipoEnvio(TipoEnvio);
            this.ex.setPaisDestino(PaisDestino);
            this.ex.setCiudadOrigen(CiudadOrigen);
            this.ex.setCiudadDestino(CiudadDestino);
            this.ex.setMonedaPago(MonedaPago);
            this.ex.setNombreEmpleado(NombreEmpleado);
            this.ex.setNombreFuncionario(NombreFuncionario);
            int r = this.met.agregar(this.ex);
            if (r == 1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) null, "Exportación creada con éxito");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) null, "No se pudo crear exportación");
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) null, "El campo CantidadPro debe ser numérico");
        }
    }

    public void actualizarExportacion() {
        Connection cn = Conexion.Conectar();
        int filaSeleccionada = this.exv.tabla.getSelectedRow();
        if (filaSeleccionada == -1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) null, "Debe seleccionar una fila para actualizar");
            return;
        }
        try {
            int id = Integer.parseInt(this.exv.tabla.getValueAt(filaSeleccionada, 0).toString());
            String NombrePro = this.exv.TxtNombreP.getText();
            String PresentacionPro = this.exv.TxtPresentacionProducto.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String CantidadPro = this.exv.TxtCantidad.getText();
            String TipoEnvio = this.exv.TxtEnvio.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String PaisDestino = this.exv.TxtPaises.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String CiudadOrigen = this.exv.TxtCuidadOrigen.getText();
            String CiudadDestino = this.exv.TxtCiudadDestino.getText();
            String MonedaPago = this.exv.TxtMonedaPago.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String NombreEmpleado = this.exv.TxtNombreEmp.getText();
            String NombreFuncionario = this.exv.TxtNombreFunci.getText();
            if (NombrePro.isEmpty() || PresentacionPro.isEmpty() || CantidadPro.isEmpty() || TipoEnvio.isEmpty() || PaisDestino.isEmpty() || CiudadOrigen.isEmpty() || CiudadDestino.isEmpty() || MonedaPago.isEmpty() || NombreEmpleado.isEmpty() || NombreFuncionario.isEmpty()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) null, "Debe completar todos los campos");
                return;
            }
            try {
                Integer.parseInt(CantidadPro);
                PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement("UPDATE exportacion SET NombrePro=?, PresentacionPro=?, CantidadPro=?, TipoEnvio=?, CiudadOrigen=?, CiudadDestino=?, PaisDestino=?, MonedaPago=?, NombreEmpleado=?, NombreFuncionario=? WHERE id=?");
                ps.setString(1, NombrePro);
                ps.setString(2, PresentacionPro);
                ps.setString(3, CantidadPro);
                ps.setString(4, TipoEnvio);
                ps.setString(5, CiudadOrigen);
                ps.setString(6, CiudadDestino);
                ps.setString(7, PaisDestino);
                ps.setString(8, MonedaPago);
                ps.setString(9, NombreEmpleado);
                ps.setString(10, NombreFuncionario);
                ps.setInt(11, id);
                int resultado = ps.executeUpdate();
                if (resultado > 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) null, "Exportación actualizada con éxito");
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) null, "No se pudo actualizar la exportación");
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) null, "La cantidad debe ser un valor numérico");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) null, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void mostrarExportacionParaEditar() {
        int fila = this.exv.tabla.getSelectedRow();
        if (fila == -1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this.exv, "Debe seleccionar una expotación");
            return;
        }
        int id = Integer.parseInt(this.exv.tabla.getValueAt(fila, 0).toString());
        String NombrePro = (String) this.exv.tabla.getValueAt(fila, 1);
        String PresentacionPro = this.exv.tabla.getValueAt(fila, 2).toString();
        String CantidadPro = this.exv.tabla.getValueAt(fila, 3).toString();
        String TipoEnvio = this.exv.tabla.getValueAt(fila, 4).toString();
        String PaisDestino = this.exv.tabla.getValueAt(fila, 5).toString();
        String CiudadOrigen = this.exv.tabla.getValueAt(fila, 6).toString();
        String CiudadDestino = this.exv.tabla.getValueAt(fila, 7).toString();
        String MonedaPago = this.exv.tabla.getValueAt(fila, 8).toString();
        String NombreEmpleado = this.exv.tabla.getValueAt(fila, 9).toString();
        String NombreFuncionario = this.exv.tabla.getValueAt(fila, 10).toString();
        this.exv.TxtId.setText(id);
        this.exv.TxtNombreP.setText(NombrePro);
        this.exv.TxtPresentacionProducto.setSelectedItem(PresentacionPro);
        this.exv.TxtCantidad.setText(CantidadPro);
        this.exv.TxtEnvio.setSelectedItem(TipoEnvio);
        this.exv.TxtPaises.setSelectedItem(PaisDestino);
        this.exv.TxtCuidadOrigen.setText(CiudadOrigen);
        this.exv.TxtCiudadDestino.setText(CiudadDestino);
        this.exv.TxtMonedaPago.setSelectedItem(MonedaPago);
        this.exv.TxtNombreEmp.setText(NombreEmpleado);
        this.exv.TxtNombreFunci.setText(NombreFuncionario);
        this.exv.BtnGuardar.setEnabled(false);
        this.exv.BtnActualizar.setEnabled(true);
    }

    public void Registrar() {
        String nombre = this.reg.TxtNombres.getText();
        String apellidos = this.reg.TxtApellidos.getText();
        String correo = this.reg.txtCorreo.getText();
        String usuario = this.reg.TxtUsuario.getText();
        String contrasena = this.reg.TxtContrasena.getText();
        boolean camposValidos = true;
        if (nombre.equals("") || apellidos.equals("") || correo.equals("") || usuario.equals("") || contrasena.equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) null, "Debe completar todos los datos");
            camposValidos = false;
        }
        if (camposValidos && !this.validacion.validarCorreo(correo)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) null, "El correo electrónico no es válido", "Error de validación", 0);
            camposValidos = false;
        }
        if (camposValidos) {
            this.x.setNombres(this.reg.TxtNombres.getText());
            this.x.setApellidos(this.reg.TxtApellidos.getText());
            this.x.setCorreo(this.reg.txtCorreo.getText());
            this.x.setUsuario(this.reg.TxtUsuario.getText());
            this.x.setContrasena(this.reg.TxtContrasena.getText());
            Metodos metodos = this.met;
            if (Metodos.InsertarUsuario(this.x)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) null, "Usuario registrado");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) null, "Usuario no registrado");
            }
        }
    }

    public void Ingreso() {
        String us = this.log.TxtUsuario.getText();
        String pw = this.log.TxtContrasena.getText();
        Metodos metodos = this.met;
        if (Metodos.Autentificacion(us, pw).booleanValue()) {
            this.exv.setVisible(true);
            this.log.setVisible(false);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) null, "Ingreso correcto");
            return;
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) null, "Usuario no registrado");
    }

    void limpiarTabla() {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.exv.tabla.getRowCount(); i = (i - 1) + 1) {
            this.modelo.removeRow(i);
        }
    }

    void limpiarFormulario() {
        this.exv.TxtId.setText("");
        this.exv.TxtNombreP.setText("");
        this.exv.TxtPresentacionProducto.setSelectedItem("Seleccione");
        this.exv.TxtCantidad.setText("");
        this.exv.TxtEnvio.setSelectedItem("Seleccione");
        this.exv.TxtPaises.setSelectedItem("Seleccione");
        this.exv.TxtCuidadOrigen.setText("");
        this.exv.TxtCiudadDestino.setText("");
        this.exv.TxtMonedaPago.setSelectedItem("Seleccione");
        this.exv.TxtNombreEmp.setText("");
        this.exv.TxtNombreFunci.setText("");
        this.exv.txtBuscar.setText("");
        this.reg.TxtNombres.setText("");
        this.reg.TxtApellidos.setText("");
        this.reg.txtCorreo.setText("");
        this.reg.TxtUsuario.setText("");
        this.reg.TxtContrasena.setText("");
        this.log.TxtUsuario.setText("");
        this.log.TxtContrasena.setText("");
    }

    public void delete() {
        int fila = this.exv.tabla.getSelectedRow();
        if (fila == -1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this.exv, "Debe seleccionar una expotación");
            return;
        }
        int id = Integer.parseInt(this.exv.tabla.getValueAt(this.exv.tabla.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
        this.met.delete(id);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this.exv, "Expotación eliminada");
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) throws SQLException {
        buscarDatos();
    }

    public void buscarDatos() {
        String textoBusqueda = this.exv.txtBuscar.getText();
        Connection cn = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            try {
                cn = Conexion.Conectar();
                ps = cn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM exportacion WHERE id LIKE ? OR NombrePro LIKE ? OR PresentacionPro LIKE ? OR CantidadPro LIKE ? OR TipoEnvio LIKE ? OR CiudadOrigen LIKE ? OR CiudadDestino LIKE ? OR PaisDestino LIKE ? OR MonedaPago LIKE ? OR NombreEmpleado LIKE ? OR NombreFuncionario LIKE ?");
                ps.setString(1, "%" + textoBusqueda + "%");
                ps.setString(2, "%" + textoBusqueda + "%");
                ps.setString(3, "%" + textoBusqueda + "%");
                ps.setString(4, "%" + textoBusqueda + "%");
                ps.setString(5, "%" + textoBusqueda + "%");
                ps.setString(6, "%" + textoBusqueda + "%");
                ps.setString(7, "%" + textoBusqueda + "%");
                ps.setString(8, "%" + textoBusqueda + "%");
                ps.setString(9, "%" + textoBusqueda + "%");
                ps.setString(10, "%" + textoBusqueda + "%");
                ps.setString(11, "%" + textoBusqueda + "%");
                rs = ps.executeQuery();
                DefaultTableModel modelo = this.exv.tabla.getModel();
                modelo.setRowCount(0);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    Object[] fila = {Integer.valueOf(rs.getInt("id")), rs.getString("NombrePro"), rs.getString("PresentacionPro"), rs.getString("CantidadPro"), rs.getString("TipoEnvio"), rs.getString("PaisDestino"), rs.getString("CiudadOrigen"), rs.getString("CiudadDestino"), rs.getString("MonedaPago"), rs.getString("NombreEmpleado"), rs.getString("NombreFuncionario")};
                    modelo.addRow(fila);
                }
                if (rs != null) {
                    try {
                        rs.close();
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) null, "Error al cerrar la conexión: " + ex.getMessage());
                        return;
                    }
                }
                if (ps != null) {
                    ps.close();
                }
                if (cn != null) {
                    cn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex2) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) null, "Error al buscar los datos: " + ex2.getMessage());
                if (rs != null) {
                    try {
                        rs.close();
                    } catch (SQLException ex3) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) null, "Error al cerrar la conexión: " + ex3.getMessage());
                        return;
                    }
                }
                if (ps != null) {
                    ps.close();
                }
                if (cn != null) {
                    cn.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            if (rs != null) {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex4) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog((Component) null, "Error al cerrar la conexión: " + ex4.getMessage());
                    throw th;
                }
            }
            if (ps != null) {
                ps.close();
            }
            if (cn != null) {
                cn.close();
            }
            throw th;
        }
    }
}
```

lo que necesito es en vez de lo que hace ese software; que mi software con la misma estructura que el anterior; pero que sirva para  crear, consultar, eliminar y editar un usuario o un empleado cualquiera, el cliente, el pedido y el producto.

Lo que he hecho para solucionar ese problema es buscar en youtube; ¿ Como codificar un programa en java para insertar unos datos en la clasificación relativa a esos datos y poder modificarla en mysql; con la misma estructura que el anterior código ?; solo encontré un video que solucionaba el problema era: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RPvxZzkXaTk; y no tenía la estructura usada en el anterior código; por eso necesito que me ayuden explicandome ¿ Como codificar un programa en java para insertar unos datos en la clasificación relativa a esos datos y poder modificarla en mysql; con la misma estructura que el código de este POST ?

Comment: he editado el mensaje

Comment: si entiendes la razón del problema te recomiendo escribir una respuesta a tu propio problema

Comment: Podrías empezar por buscar tutoriales relacionados con las librerías que ocupa la clase que compartiste. BUSCA ->  java.awt  tutorial -> java.sql tutorial->javax.swing tutorial. Y busca un tutorial que te explique como crear un CRUD relacionado a esas librerias así podrás "crear, consultar, eliminar y editar un usuario"

Comment: Trata de buscar la documentación de la libería que quieres usar para resolver tu problema, de antemano tu código está muy denso, trata de dividir la lógica en diferentes archivos para que no tengas un solo archivo muy grande.

Comment: Hola Eljuicioso, bienvenido, me atrevo a vaticinar, que nadie va a contestar tu pregunta, porque es demasiado extensa, te sugiero que la edites, dividas el problema en pequeños problemas, y dejes uno de ellos, para que sea asumible el responder, y luego vayas haciendo las preguntas restantes.

Answer (score 3):

Partiendo del presupuesto de que la pregunta "Cómo hacer un programa..." es una que no puede (ni debe) responderse aquí, el objetivo que te has propuesto puede inscribirse bajo la rúbrica:

### Cómo escribir un programa en Java con una interfaz gráfica basada en Swing que permita al usuario conectarse a una base de datos y realizar operaciones básicas CRUD (*Create, Read, Update, Delete*) sobre la información.

Entender esta terminología y saber definir con precisión los requisitos del programa es importante: te ayudará enormemente a encontrar la documentación, tutoriales y guías que necesitas.

Dicho esto, aprender a codificar una interfaz gráfica decente con manejo de eventos, a entender la conexión de la API de JDBC con una base de datos MySQL u otra cualquiera y a escribir los métodos necesarios en el código para practicar las operaciones CRUD no son habilidades triviales que aprenderás viendo un solo vídeo. Necesitarás ver muchos vídeos y picar bastante código.

En español, uno de los tutoriales más sólidos y mejor explicados es el excelente [Curso de Java desde 0](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLU8oAlHdN5BktAXdEVCLUYzvDyqRQJ2lk) del canal [PildorasInformaticas](https://www.youtube.com/@pildorasinformaticas) en YouTube impartido por el profesor Juan Díaz. Concretamente en los vídeos [203](https://youtu.be/cFLsynl91B0) a 229 podrás aprender lo esencial de cómo conectar un programa escrito en Java a una base de datos MySQL. Si necesitas también aprender a construir interfaces gráficas de Java Swing con solvencia, deberás estudiar los vídeos [57](https://youtu.be/7q2VBGIKeYc) a 133 de este curso. Son más de 30 horas de estudio y programación, pero será una inversión de tiempo fructífera.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [answer] y  [CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido), saludos.